# Window functions vs vanilla SQL

Tags: sql, database, analytic-functions

If we would consider window functions as an extension to vanilla SQL, what is their advantage over it?

Can you perform queries and things that wouldn't be possible with 'plain' SQL?

Comment: Window functions have been a part of ANSI SQL for almost two decades.  Why would you consider them an extension?  But a simple answer to your question is that they are more concise, faster, and expand functionality of basic SQL.  Perhaps that's why they are in the standard.

Comment: 'extension ' was used as a way to disambiguate the scope of the question;if you can have the same outcome without using window functions

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is "yes", you can do things that wouldn't be possible otherwise -- at least not in a single query.

A simple example is `row_number()`, which you cannot replicate (in a single select) on a table that has no unique keys.

Comment: And replicating row_number on a table *with* unique keys whilst possible would likely be horrifically inefficient with a triangular join with quadratic complexity.